# pip3 install of jupyter issues: 'notebook' is not a Jupyter command

Tags: python, pip

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and installed jupyter using `pip3 install jupyter` [as described on the jupyter.org website](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#new-to-python-and-jupyter).

The install appeared to work without issue. There were no missing zeromq references as reported in some other forum posts.

But I had two issues:

1. There's no `jupyter` command installed. I launched `jupyter` using:

   ```
   python3 ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter.py notebook
   ```
2. The app failed to start after issuing the following message:

   ```
   jupyter: 'notebook' is not a Jupyter command.
   ```

I prefer to keep the install fairly minimal so I'm avoiding going the anaconda route.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around a little bit I discovered the `.local/bin` directory (apparently my linux sys admin knowledge needs an update).

Running jupyter out of `~/.local/bin` seems to work fine.

Comment: If you are using `pip install` with `--user` option then you should [add `~/.local/bin` to your `$PATH`](http://askubuntu.com/q/60218/3712)

Comment: Yes,  understanding where it was installed was the difficult part. Incidentally I ran pip from my user account without --user and the install was still in .local, I assume because the account I ran from didn't have root permissions.

Comment: [the upstream `pip` issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668) is still open. Though Ubuntu's version defaults to `--user` outside virtualenv since Ubuntu 15.04. See [LP #1419695](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1419695).